# Why De la Cruz did not pass onto the 'Final death'?

Tags: coco

In the movie, De la Cruz is so busy to organize and celebrate the Day of the Dead (in the Land of the Dead, of course) and does not even seem to care about returning and meeting his family (if he has one?)

There are apparently so many people who remember him because he's famous. The movie didn't mention about his family but I suppose he doesn't have any descendant to remember him. (TBD)

Why didn't he pass onto the Final Death?

> Héctor explained to Miguel that **unless there's a relative in the living world who remembers their ancestor, their spirit passes onto what they call the final death**, the same fate that awaits him if Miguel doesn't take his photo home. *([Disney Wikia](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/H%C3%A9ctor))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my own assumption, to avoid final death all one has to do is to ***remember said person*** and it has nothing to do with family and relatives. If you remember:

**Spoiler alert:** Before Hector actually knows that *Miguel is his great great grandson*, he just wanted Miguel to put his photo among Miguels ancestors so that he can cross.

> Miguel encounters Héctor, a down-on-his-luck skeleton who once played with Ernesto and offers to help Miguel reach him. In return, *Héctor asks Miguel to take his photo back to the Land of the Living so he can visit his daughter before she forgets him and he disappears completely.*  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco_(2017_film)#Plot)

Thus based on that assumption, since everyone remembers De la Cruz and if you notice, ***the flowers leading to De la Cruz's museum***, it's understandable that De La Cruz is remembered enough to not pass onto "Final Death".